# How to change language (localisation) within the app in swift 5?

Tags: ios, swift, localization

I am trying to localise iOS app which is developed in Swift 5. I have done with all localisation things in code as well as in storyboard. But I am not sure how to change language within the app when i click on Language Button.

Is this possible to change app language within app? if yes How?

Please suggest best possible way to do same

Answer (score 1):

I just did a similar implementation. Glad you asked and I saw this. Here is my implementation. You can modify.

```
enum Language: String, CaseIterable {
    case english, german

    var code: String {
        switch self {
        case .english: return "en"
        case .german: return "de"
        }
    }

    static var selected: Language {
        set {
            UserDefaults.standard.set([newValue.code], forKey: "AppleLanguages")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue.rawValue, forKey: "language")
        }
        get {
            return Language(rawValue: UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "language") ?? "") ?? .english
        }
    }

    static func switchLanguageBetweenEnglishAndGerman() {
        selected = selected == .english ? .german : .english
    }
}
```

Now you just need to call `Language.selected == .german` and reload the views.

Comment: Thanks for quick help. by using this will i able to change language in whole app or just for single screen which i reload ?

Comment: Views that are already loaded won't change. You need to do it manually for each view components.

Comment: @Frankenstein, how does it work when we are considering languages like Arabic, Hebrew etc. as the user interface is aligning from right to left. I think reloading the views will not switch the alignments of entire view system. If it does so, then can you please share the way to work out.

Comment: It should work as expected if you are using auto-layout if not it won't. And this is a topic entirely different from this question. You could search for language support for right aligning languages. To start of check here https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-support-right-to-left-languages.

Comment: will this work only if i restarted app, because language is not changing on the fly

Answer (score 0):

To change localization throughout the app. For that, You need to follow the below step.

Create a Parent class of every `UIViewController` and define `setupLocasitation` method for further usage.

## ParentViewController.swift

```
class ParentViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    func setupLocasitation(){

    }
}
```

All other class of UIViewController should be a subclass of `ParentViewController` and  override `setupLocasitation` method

## ViewController1.swift

```
class ViewController1: ParentViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupLocasitation()
    }

    override func setupLocasitation() {
        super.setupLocasitation()
        print("Your localisation specifi code here...")
    }
}
```

## ViewController2.swift

```
class ViewController2: ParentViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupLocasitation()            
    }

    override func setupLocasitation() {
        super.setupLocasitation()
        print("Your localisation specifi code here...")
    }   
}
```

## ChangeLanguageVC.swift

You need to grab all instances of `ParentViewController` and force-fully call the `setupLocasitation` method.

```
class ChangeLanguageVC: ParentViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupLocasitation()
    }

    @IBAction func btnChangeLanguageTap(){
        //Code for your language changes here...

        let viewControllers = self.navigationController?.viewControllers ?? []
        for vc in viewControllers{
            if let parent = vc as? ParentViewController{
                parent.setupLocasitation()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//
//  LanguageExtensions.swift
//  Flourish
//
//  Created by Janko on 11/11/2020.
//

import Foundation
import UIKit
let languageKey = "languageKey"
var language : Int {
    switch UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: languageKey) {
    case "en":
        return 0
    case "dutch":
        return 1
    default:
        return 0
    }
}
extension String {
    func localizedLanguage()->String?{
        var defaultLanguage = "en"

        if let selectedLanguage = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: languageKey){
            defaultLanguage = selectedLanguage
        }
        return NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: defaultLanguage, comment: "")

    }
}



class LanguageLabel: UILabel{
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(updateUI), name: AppNotification.changeLanguage, object: nil)
    }
    @IBInspectable var localizedLanguage: String? {
        didSet{
            updateUI()
        }
    }

   @objc func updateUI(){
        if let string = localizedLanguage {
            text = string.localizedLanguage()
        }
    }
}

class LanguageButton: UIButton{
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(updateUI), name: AppNotification.changeLanguage, object: nil)
    }
    @IBInspectable var localizedLanguage: String? {
        didSet{
            updateUI()
        }
    }

    @objc func updateUI(){
        if let string = localizedLanguage {
            setTitle(string.localizedLanguage(), for: .normal)
        }
    }
}
struct AppNotification{
    static  let changeLanguage = Notification.Name("changeLanguage")
}
extension UIViewController{
    func changeLanguage(){
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Change Language", message: "Change it", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let actionEnglish = UIAlertAction(title: "English", style: .default) { (action) in
            UserDefaults.standard.setValue("en", forKey: languageKey)
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: AppNotification.changeLanguage , object: nil)
        }
        let actionMontenegrin = UIAlertAction(title: "Montenegrinish", style: .default) { (action) in
            UserDefaults.standard.setValue("dutch", forKey: languageKey)
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: AppNotification.changeLanguage , object: nil)
        }
        alert.addAction(actionEnglish)
        alert.addAction(actionMontenegrin)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```